Solve Minimax Rules in Finite Case
Let $\Theta = \{\theta_1, \cdots, \theta_n\}$ be the space of parameters and $D = \{d_1, \cdots, d_m\}$ be the space of decisions (that is, they are arbitrary finite sets with at least two elements). A loss function $L : \Theta \times D \to [0, \infty)$ is given and known. Write $a_{ij} = L(\theta_i, d_j)$. We consider the problem of finding all minimax decisions over the collection of all random decisions. That is, we would like to find :
\begin{equation*}
\text{argmin} \max_{i = 1, \ldots, n}\sum_{j=1}^ma_{ij}p_j
\end{equation*}
The minimum is taken over all $p = (p_1, \cdots, p_m) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $p_i \geqslant 0$ and $\sum_{j=1}^m p_{j}=1$.
I post here three questions. The first two is merely out of curiosity so answer them if you can. The answer to the last question is what I am really looking for.

Do we have an algorithm (or closed form) to find any one element of the argmin set (so that we can compute the minimax risk) ? (The algorithm must not be numerical approximation.)
Do we have an algorithm (or closed form) to find all elements of the argmin set ? (The algorithm must not be numerical approximation.)
Suppose that $n = 2$ and $m = 3$. Do we have a closed mathematical form of every element in the argmin set ?

For question 3, if we write $p_3 = 1-p_1-p_2$, then we are minimizing, over all $p_1+p_2 \leqslant 1$, $p_1 \geqslant 0$ and $p_2 \geqslant 0$, the quantity :
\begin{equation*}
\max \{a_{13} + p_1(a_{11}-a_{13}) + p_2(a_{12}-a_{13}), a_{23} + p_1(a_{21}-a_{23}) + p_2(a_{22}-a_{23})\}
\end{equation*}
This is like a plane slightly folded. The answer would probably need to discuss by cases on the signs of $a_{ij}-a_{ij'}$ and the closed form would probably have to depend on these cases.
